# Error in Jasmine test from Google Analytics in Angular app

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm working on some unit tests for my Angular app using Karma + Jasmine in a Grunt build. I have the following run block code that sets up Google Analytics:

```
run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$state', '$location', '$auth', '$window', 'AUTH_EVENTS', 'AuthService', 'Permission'];

function run($rootScope, $state, $location, $auth, $window, AUTH_EVENTS, AuthService, Permission) {
    // Initialize Google Analytics for tracking page views w/ ui-router state changes
    $window.ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
```

When running `grunt test` I'm getting the following error from the `$window.ga(..` line:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$window.ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', 'auto')')
```

If I remove the line completely, the error is gone and the Jasmine tests continue on through just fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We provide all the JavaScript files which are used by Jasmine in karma.conf.js file to load dependencies.You get undefined because Jasmine cannot find ga function which is defined in analytics.js. To avoid this error you may want to mock it like below

```
var $rootScope, $window;

beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$window_) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $window = _$window_;
    $window.ga = function(){};
}));
```

Comment: I guess the downside of this is that I'll have to mock it for each test file. Thanks for answer.

Comment: instead you can include googleanalytics.js as a dependency in karma's configuration file under files[...]

Comment: I have included googleanalytics.js in karma's configuration file and also tried with the above code but still getting error  "$window.ga is not a function" @akniazi